# Upload multiple files with PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to use this code to upload multiple files with PHP 5.5 and attach to an email. If I take the brackets from `file[]` (so it's `file`) on the `name` attribute of the `input` field, I'm able to successfully upload one file; if I put the brackets back on, the page gives this warning (for the line with the call to `file_get_contents()`) and attaches a file to the email called `Array.dat` but not the selected file. What am I doing wrong?

```
Warning: file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in C:\wamp\www\myapp\submit.php on line 188
```

**HTML:**

```
<input id="file" name="file[]" type="file" multiple="true">
```

**PHP:**

```
$fullmessage = "This is a multi-part fullname in MIME format.

--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_2_$boundary\"

--_2_$boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

$msg_quoted

--_2_$boundary--\r\n";

$msg_b64 = base64_encode($msg);

$fullmessage .= "--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$date->format('U')."-".$company."-".$custname."-".$email.".txt\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment

$msg_b64\r\n";

foreach($_FILES as $f){
  if($f['size'] > 0){
  $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($f['tmp_name'])));
   $name = $f['name'];

   $fullmessage .= "--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$name\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment

$attachment\r\n";
  }
}

$fullmessage .= "--_1_$boundary--";
$mail_options = '';
$mail_options .= 'O DeliveryMode=b'; //tells sendmail to run asynchronously
mail(EMAIL_RECIPIENTS, $subject, $fullmessage, $headers, $mail_options);
```

**Update:** This fixed it, thanks to @I'L'I:

```
// Process the uploaded files.
$num_files = count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

for($i=0; $i < $num_files; $i++){   
    if($_FILES['file']['size'][$i] > 0){
        $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i])));
        $name = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];

        $fullmessage .= "--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$name\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment

$attachment\r\n";
  }  
}
```

Comment: strongly suggest replacing php's mail() with a library like swiftmailer or phpmailer

Comment: Thanks, Dagon. But I don't have control over that part of the app. Can this code be salvaged somehow?

Comment: @Alex, glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this problem is more a matter of what the error indicates:

> Warning: file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path,
>   array given in C:\wamp\www\myapp\submit.php on line 188.

`file_get_contents` expects a `string`, ***not*** an `array`.

So there's a couple of things you can do to fix this:

Either use the correct string:

```
  $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($f)));
```

Or use the `key` of the `$_FILES` array

```
for ($x=0; $x<sizeof($_FILES); $x++) {
    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES[$x])));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @I'L'I. Please see update above. You got me on the right track and then a bit more tweaking got it working for multiple files.

Comment: Another issue: It's uploading the file but Irfanview says `Can't read file header!`. I'm uploading some JPG files to test and their content or mime type is getting lost.

Comment: Is it only with `JPG's` or is it with other formats too, and how are you decoding the files?

Comment: It's doing it with all file types. It's a decoding issue. PDFs generate the error `...sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded.` How do you decode the attachments? Shouldn't they automatically be recognized?

Comment: Usually the standard `base64_decode()` is all that is required. I tested a few `PNG`'s (chunked and base64 encoded) as you have and it seemed to work fine. If you want to post that portion of your code I'll take a look; It's easy to double decode something by accident causing the header to get mucked.

Comment: Another thing you could try is to remove the line `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`. The content should already be encoded — this could be double-encoding it.

Comment: Thanks, @I'L'I. I've added the page's code under the `Code for the page` section above. One other thing: I'm using the Test Mail Server Tool (http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/) to handle the SMTP on my local machine. Could that be causing any issues?

Comment: I believe it's the way your mail headers are constructed. Replace it with this `$fullmessage .= "--AlexMail\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\".$name.\"\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: BASE64\nContent-Disposition: attachment\n\n$attachment\r\n\n--AlexMail";` ... The linebreaks are essential for it work properly.

Comment: Not much luck. Tried your suggestion. Something is still screwy.

Comment: Also, the file sizes on the file attachments are wrong when I get the email.

Comment: Finally got it working! The files come through with no issues. The code is almost identical to earlier versions. I'll post it tomorrow.

Comment: The **Update** section above now has the code that works. Thanks again, @I'L'I.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot usually upload more than one file with only one file input element. The only browser I encountered that supports it was Opera, and they removed the feature, probably because of lack of server side support.

And that is exactly what you are experiencing: If you change the name of the form field from being a single name into pointing to an array, you have to change the access to the file data on the PHP side. If you say you cannot use a decent library for mailing, I assume you cannot change the PHP code that receives the files. Then you cannot change the one-file upload into a multi-file upload.

And please consider not trying to create such a multi-file input field on the HTML side because no user is knowing that he might be able to send more than one file - and even if you tell them they can, they don't know how.

Comment: Thanks, Sven. I can change the code above but can't add any other libraries for mailing.

Comment: Then why don't you concatenate one library you selected into this one file you can change? Yes, file size will be huge, but convenience and security will also benefit hugely.